# Why this function return Nan error?

Tags: javascript

When I click "+ 1", then in the "0" appears "NaN". Why ?

HTML:

```
<table>
<tr><td id="run">0</td></tr>
</table>
<a href="#" onclick="plus();">+ 1 </a>
```

JS:

```
function plus(){
document.getElementById("run").innerHTML = ( document.getElementById("run").value + 1 );
}
```

Comment: Maybe another ay you could do this: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/UUdV8/

Answer (score 5):

It happens because `value` property can be applied only to `input` or `select` elements.

Pay attention that you need to convert your string value to numeric, otherwise you will get string concatenation. It can be done with [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) or [`parseFloat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) functions.

```
var val = parseInt(document.getElementById("run").innerHTML, 10);
document.getElementById("run").innerHTML = ( val + 1 );
```

Comment: What are the parentheses around the `val + 1` about?

Comment: @JaredFarrish It's harmless but "highlights" the addition in the code.

Comment: *"highlights" the addition in the code* - Ok. Personally, I think it's confusing and useless and prone to confusion in beginners who will replicate it. But, y'know, I guess that's how it goes. `:)`

Answer (score 4):

That's because:

```
document.getElementById("run").value
```

will be `undefined` and `undefined + 1 == NaN`.

Input boxes have a `value` property, but nodes like `<td />` have `.innerHTML()` or `.innerText()`.

Also, note that `'0' + 1 == '01'`, so you have to do some casting as well:

```
parseInt(document.getElementById('run').innerHTML, 10) + 1;
```

The additional radix - 10 - is necessary to convert strings that may be interpreted as octal numbers :)

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't thinking `td` elements had `value` attributes. Guess there's a mad rush to correct all of the other answers in three, two, one...

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function plus(){
document.getElementById("run").innerHTML = parseInt( document.getElementById("run").value) + 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because attribute values are always strings and string + 1 is a NaN in JavaScript.

To solve this, use `string.toFloat()`:

```
function plus(){
    document.getElementById("run").innerHTML = ( document.getElementById("run").value.toFloat() + 1 );
}
```

Or use [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt):

```
function plus(){
    document.getElementById("run").innerHTML = ( parseInt(document.getElementById("run").value) + 1 );
}
```

Or use the [`~~()`](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/double-bitwise-not/) function as a trick, but this will result in a not readable source.

Comment: "string + 1 is a NaN" - not true unfortunately.

Comment: `~~` truncates a number. If want to show other possibilities for converting types, try `Number()` or `+`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this question still deserve a better answer, but I may be wrong. )

Let's check what happens in your `plus` function. First, you get an element by its id, with

```
var targetElement = document.getElementById('run');
```

It's actually a reference to the object of [DOMElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element) type. Which is quite easy to see by checking its nodeType property.

```
if (targetElement.nodeType === 1) { alert("It's an element!"); }
```

DOM Elements have plenty of nice properties, but their `nodeValue` is *always equal to null*. So if you want to work with its text content, you can either look for the child textNodes - or just use `innerHTML` property. It's a string, yes, but Javascript will manage to convert it to a normal number if it's numeric (and 0 is numeric, from what I remember :).

So your `plus` function can be actually written just like this ([the proof](http://jsfiddle.net/s4KNe/)):

```
document.getElementById('run').innerHTML++;
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `value` is a property of [HTMLInputElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/HTMLInputElement) and the `TD` element is not an `HTMLInputElement` but a `HTMLTableCellElement`, so doesn't have that property and:

```
undefined + 1; // NaN - Not a Number
```

You can basically use the same `innerHTML` property you used to set the content also to get it:

```
function plus() {
    // no need to execute `getElementById` twice
    var td = document.getElementById("run");

    td.innerHTML = +td.innerHTML + 1;
}
```

To convert the value in Number I used the [unary plus operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#.2B_%28Unary_Plus%29). You could also check if it's `NaN` before use it, something like:

```
function plus() {
    var td = document.getElementById("run");
    var value = +td.innerHTML || 0;

    td.innerHTML = value + 1;
}
```

In that case if it's `NaN` (or 0, but in that case it's an identity) will set to 0, and the count will start from `1` without give any error.

Additionally, I would say that it could be better use the [textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Node.textContent) property where supported, but then the code will be a bit more complex to handle all browser's (e.g. in some IE versions you need to use `innerText` instead), and `innerHTML`could be good in most of the cases.